AccessDenied Error with Policy Condition Failed for Content-Disposition in S3 Presigned POST Request
I am creating an S3-signed URL using the following function:
return s3_resource.meta.client.generate_presigned_post(
Bucket=S3Config.BUCKET_NAME,
Key=object_key,
Fields={
    "Content-Disposition": f"filename={filename}",
    "Content-Type": mime_type
},
Conditions=[
    {"Content-Disposition": f'filename="{filename}"'},
    {"Content-Type": mime_type}
],
ExpiresIn=120

)
When submitting the request from Postman, sending the required parameters in the form (i.e., key, AWSAccessKeyId, policy, signature, file, Content-Disposition, Content-Type), I am getting this error:
AccessDenied
    Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "$Content-Disposition", "filename=\"test.png\""]
    ZDV7NSW88AAV90EX
    1dPHZL4l3wQvWfHQlfF0+z/Yi2rC3e8eS6tV8BjlFwIiJlYIrL9qJhUbjMAKCnm2pNl+B37QACs=


Content-Disposition should be: attachment; filename=your_filename_here

In the Fields or in Conditions?

There is no such Content-Disposition: filename,  mdn

I want to send it as a meta data and set it on the S3.

What difference does it make? Again, it doesn't exist

I updated my code as {"Content-Disposition":f'attachment; filename="{filename}"'. But I am getting the same error.

If it still doesn't work I can't help anymore...
